# Split a string containing various spaces

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I have txt file as follows and would like to split them into double arrays

```
node Strain    Axis  Strain  F      P/S   Sum    Cur     Moment
0   0.00000    0.00  0.0000     0     0     0     0      0.00
1   0.00041  -83.19  0.0002  2328   352     0     0     -0.80
2   0.00045  -56.91  0.0002  2329   352     0     0      1.45
3   0.00050  -42.09  0.0002  2327   353     0     0     -0.30
```

My goal is to have a series of arrays of each column. i.e. 
     node[] = {0,1,2,3), Axis[]= {0.00,-83.19,-56.91,-42.09}, ....

I know how to read the txt file and covert strings to double arrays.  but the problem is the values are not separated by tab, but by different number of spaces.  I googled to find out a way to do it. However, I couldn't find any.  some discussed a way to do with a constant spaces. If you know how to do or there is an existing Q&A for this issue and let me know, it will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks,

Comment: Can't you read them by position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntires` should do the trick:

```
var items = source.Split(new [] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

> The return value does not include array elements that contain an empty string

Answer (score 3):

A different way, although I would suggest you stick with the other answers here using `RemoveEmptyEntries` would be to use a regular expression, but in this case it is overkill:

```
string[] elements = Regex.Split(s, @"\s+");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var doubles = text.Split("\n\r".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
              .Skip(1)
              .Select(line => line.Split(new char[]{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                  .Select(x => double.Parse(x)).ToArray())
              .ToArray();
```

Comment: Should probably use `Environment.NewLine` instead of messing up the CRLF.

Comment: @McAden No, text can be prepared in one environment and parsed in another. It is good while in *writing*, not in *reading*

Comment: @McAden *Nix'es use a single char (`\n`).

Comment: I'm aware, was just pointing out that your code is using `\n\r` which I don't think is very common. Ultimately it depends on where the OP is pulling his data from. Your code is the most correct otherwise though and I +1'd.

Comment: @McAden I don't think you really understant this code fully. it creates an array(`"\n\r".ToCharArray()`), order is not important. Same as `"\r\n".ToCharArray()`

Comment: I read it too fast and didn't even notice the `.ToCharArray()`. You're correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use the option [`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to treat consecutive delimiters as one:

```
string[] parts = source.Split(' ',StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

then parse from there:

```
double[] values = parts.Select(s => double.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```